# date picker with time HH:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to implement date picker inside the gridview and the pannel, I have tried some date pickers but it doesn't have minutes or seconds. It should show the associated control date if it present. please suggest any free good date pickers. I have tried using html input type=date and time but it displays date in client format.

Answer (score 3):

For getting Time in Minutes and seconds you must use the Time Picker intent along with the date picker. You can go through the several tutorials. I got the answer through the below link. Please go through it. All the best.
http://pulse7.net/android/date-picker-dialog-time-picker-dialog-android/

Answer (score 0):

please try this bootstrap datetime picker

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/